# Algorithm for traversing the list of items (songs that are stored in history of played songs for user)

Tags: algorithm, traversal

I'm trying to develop algorithm for traversing data structure that represent list of songs in my application.

That list consists of all songs I already played (my history of playing) and other songs which I will play.

```
Something like this (example):
```

- H song 1
- H song 2
- H song 3
- H song 4
- currently playing song
- Q song in queue 5
- Q song in queue 6
- Q song in queue 7
- Q song in queue 8

I need to implement 'previous' and 'next' button so I can move around my playlist.

Everytime song is played it's stored in the history.

I need efficient algorithm (don't need code, just idea or pseudo code) that will solve all use cases when user play songs.

For example, one scenario could be:

In history there are songs 1, 2 and 3. Now we play song 4 and after that history state is 1, 2, 3 and 4.
Lets say we click 'previous' button to play again previously played song. Now history state is 1, 2, 3, 4 and 3 (song 3 was played before song 4).
Click 'previous' button again and then new history state is 1, 2, 3, 4, 3 and 2.

Lets say now we click some song in queue, for example song 6. History state is 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2 and 6. Clicking 'previous'
button now should play song 2 and add that song on the top of the history (state: 1,2,3,4,3,2,6,2)).

It would be great if I could develop some kind of data structure which will keep my history state consise and which will
allways give me previous song if look at the top of the history.

So, this data structure isn't adecvate for that problem. It keeps the history state consise but I can't figure out how I
can simple traverse through history.

Maybe algorithm for traversing would be simplier if I change data structure, but how to accomplish both request
(having consise history information and having possibility to simple get previously played song)?

Thanx very much to everyone who will contribute in this disscussion. It's good to now that I need that algorithm for
    music player at http://starvibes.com which will be 'next big thing' in my oppinion.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you could use a list to store your main playlist and another list to add the songs as they are being played. Hitting "previous" would trigger your history (second) list's last item and on another previous hit it would go back one element and so on. Hitting "next" would trigger your main list's next song.

Comment: If the "next" button navigates to the next element in the queue, then so should the "previous" button navigate to the _previous_ element _in the queue_. If you make it navigate to the previous song in play history it will break the principle of least astonishment.

Answer (score 1):

Having 2 lists definitely sounds like the way to go - your history list and your main list.

You also need an iterator into the history list. Whenever you click previous or next, you decrement or increment this iterator and get the value for that iterator. If you click a new song, reset the iterator to the back of the list (the most recently played).

Whenever a song starts playing, add it to the history list (regardless of whether it's a new song or you clicked next or previous).

Your example: (`^` indicates the position of the iterator)

```
Command   History
--------------------------------
          1, 2, 3
                ^
Play 4
          1, 2, 3, 4
                   ^
Previous
          1, 2, 3, 4, 3
                ^
Previous
          1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2
             ^
Play 6
          1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 6
                            ^
Previous
          1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 6, 2
                         ^
```

When I think about something like Winamp, where you have a list as opposed to a queue (meaning you can select any song to play, after which it will continue from there) (except that it also has a separate queue, but that's beside the point)...

Unless you're using shuffle mode, you probably want an iterator in the main list as well, which will indicate the **most recent new song** (i.e. the last song that was manually selected or by clicking `next` when at the end of the history list).

This will allow you to, after clicking `next` when at the end of the history list, go to the sequentially next song in the main list.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own data structure, inspired on LinkedList, for example, where each element knows the next and previous element.

Store your history, current element, then next elements in this structure.
When user plays a new song, you should be able to insert it quickly in the list.

Then keep a track on current (playing entry)
When user click previous, play currentEntry.previous()
When user click next, play currentEntry.next()

When user selects some other song, insert the song between currentEntry and currentEntry.next(), then play it...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would just index all the songs.

Then store the values for current song and last.

This will lead to O(1) speeds while traversing a lot of songs. Much better then a link list.

For example next() and previous() will just be a simple ++ and -- on the current song index. Where as last will just store the last song's index.

Seems pretty simple.

---

insert - add new song(++songlistsize); O(1)

remove - for(i = index; i < songlistsize; i++) songindex[i]--; 0(n)

move - swap index of songs. O(1)

---

Comment: How do you insert a song ?

Comment: @David  `That list consists of all songs I already played (my history of playing) and other songs which I will play` this is what he said he starts out with so basically just use the index's of this list.